# Fragment crashes even though it isn't selected

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app contains a ViewPager with 5 tabs. (Each tab being a fragment). Which looks something like:
  [image]

In my app, when I swipe really fast between tab 1, tab 2, and tab 3, my app crashes with an error:

> Fragment Tab5{a6f4392} not attached to Activity
>                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment

NOTE: I am not even selecting tab4 when this error occurs. I think the crash occurs because I am trying to get the context of the fragment, when it is null. But why would tab5 crash if I am not even selecting tab5 or tab4?

Comment: Share the whole stacktrace, bitte.

Comment: "But why would tab5 crash if I am not even selecting tab5 or tab4?" - if the tab 4 is not in it's final position yet and tab5 crashes, that means, that you have set [setOffscreenPageLimit(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) to 2, because by default it is 1. As soon as you select page 4, page 2 would be destroyed, and page 5 would be instantiated, that's why you get a crash on page 5.

Comment: setOffscreenPageLimit() was at it's default. However, setting it to 4 fixed my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why would tab5 crash if I am not even selecting tab5 or tab4?

ViewPager preloads always at least 1 page: the offscreen page limit of the view pager is set by default to the minimum possible value, one page to each side of the viewed page (so, 1). 
In your case, I guess it has to be > 1. Try to check it calling `getOffscreenPageLimit()`.